# NSTimers swift don't fire

Tags: swift, nstimer

I have 3 NSTimers:

```
var timer = NSTimer()
var scoreTimer = NSTimer()
var gameTmer = NSTimer()
```

Then in "viewDidLoad":

```
var sel = Selector("testFunc:")

timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: sel, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

scoreTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: sel, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

gameTmer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: sel, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

And testFunc is just like that:

```
func testFunc(timer : NSTimer){
    println("working")
}
```

But they don't work. If I try to use "fire()", then they call the testFunc, but other way - no.

Comment: I don't know too. They just don't work

Comment: Try registering the timer with `NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "testFunc:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)` (the difference is in the selector)

Comment: I tried it, didn't work

Comment: I found a solution, i deleted .scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval and added a run loop, that worked

Comment: post your answer here so it can help others.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

You can delete `.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` and add `NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)` for each timer. So, your code will look like this:

```
var sel = Selector("testFunc:")

timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: sel, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

scoreTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: sel, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

gameTmer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: sel, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)

NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(scoreTimer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)

NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(gameTmer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
```